# Use CSS to show name initials

Tags: css, overflow, truncate

Is there simple css way to reduce a name to its initials?

```
Foo Bar => F. B.
```

I came up with a (prototype) solution, but `text-overflow: '.'` does only work for firefox.

I'm looking for a css solution that works in all browsers

```css
.initials {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: '.';
    width: 2ch;
}
```

```html
<p class="initials">Foo</p> <p class="initials">Bar</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider a trick using pseudo element. Note that the use of `ch` unit is suitable when it comes to monospace fonts:

```css
.initials {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 2ch;
  font-family:monospace;
  font-size:20px;
  position: relative;
}

.initials:after {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<p class="initials">Foo</p>
<p class="initials">Bar</p>
```

In case you want transparency:

```css
.initials {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 2ch;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  letter-spacing: 1ch; /*added*/
}

.initials:after {
  content: ".";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0; /*added*/
}

body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<p class="initials">Foo</p>
<p class="initials">Bar</p>
```